# Page Returns 403 Forbidden but Only From Google Search Link

Tags: wordpress, web, google-search

I run a website http://sciantechnologies.com/.

Now, if you go to that URL, it loads fine, however if you google search "Scian Technologies", it will return a link that looks like this:

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsciantechnologies.com%2F&ei=3AY8UdLvF8Gi2gXxXg&usg=AFQjCNGT916DDNRiBhq31Qu6fz0-_GDOFg&sig2=iHtZm7pPyQGdcyZczOUMRg&bvm=bv.43287494,d.b2I

Which if you click on it, will redirect you to the correct URL, but for some reason it seems to pick up a 403 along the way. Funny thing is it leaves the correct URL in the address bar, and if you click on that and press enter, it works fine.

I didn't set up anything special here - it's just a wordpress site... anyone else had this behavior or have any ideas? I'm really scratching my head over it - it doesn't seem to make any sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who use a web provider for hosting and hit this issue, I have managed to fix this. The support team were completely useless. Anyway, I fixed this by deleting my virtual host in the gui panel (which the support team actually advised me against) and recreated it. I never saw their virtual hosts config (they refused to show it to me) but I'm guessing when I installed wp using their magical installer script,  it made changes to the virtual host configuration (most likely mod rewrite related) which I had no visibility of. Deleting the virtual domain then wiped this and started cleanly again. Note if you're doing this:

1. Delete the virtual domain and let it kick in (I.e. take your website down) before recreating it
2. There is no guarantee that deleting the virtual domain will actually wipe this configuration. It may just unlink it server side.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Google has indexed your base domain (not including www).

You'll want to put a 301 redirect to your www subdomain.

Then wait for Google to reindex your site.

Comment: Thanks for this. But not including the www also works if you type it into the address bar... is that consistent with the theory?

Comment: How are you doing your redirects?

Comment: I'm not a big networking guy, but I feel like it's something related to your wildcard "A" record in your DNS and your ServerAlias within Apache.  It's like it's dumping you into the root of your Apache server and the permission is forbidden.  The difference could be how the DNS lookup is happening on the client (ie when you hit enter) vs a redirect in your .htaccess or http.conf

Comment: With WordPress you want to avoid www at all costs especially if your into SEO. I have dealt with a few nightmares where I've converted static sites into WP sites... The SEO reciprocal link campaigns had all www. pointed... Well this was a few years ago, let's just say WordPress Mu does not like www and Google threw the sites all over the SERPS like a child throwing a fit. X_X This is just my humble opinion, I saw this happen to a few sites 2 years ago. I think www supports the no-www.org movement.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, sorry about the delayed response... I don't do any redirects - instead, I have:

1. A virtual host for our main domain name
2. A DNS record for *.domainname.com which should make sure that www.requests at least get routed (though note the google result is not for www, although www does work, though after entry, wordpress seems to truncate it)

So there actually is no .htaccess involved - you just go straight to site. There must be something special about those links though I just don't get it. Bing does the same when you click on its search result.